# Is there any way to reach the SQLite database file which I made inside of an Xamarin.Forms application?

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin, path, adb

So, I try to make an application with an SQLite database. I would like to open the database file with SQLite studio on my PC but I cant see the file. This is the path:

```
string folderpath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

I tried to pull to a folder using `adb pull data/data/[my.package.name]` but the result was:  **0 files pulled.**

I've read of the adb root but I still don't know what is it exactly, I'm just a beginner.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: yes, you can use adb to extract the file.  What is the actual path it is stored at?

Comment: @Jason On my phone? data/data/com.companyname.app/folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Root phone.
2. Copy the database data file to the mobile phone sdcard: cp (db) (sdcard).
3. Open a terminal in the folder of the computer and use: adb pull (sdcard/db) to copy to the computer.